# "Sorry, ubuntu 12.10 has experienced an internal error". How to overcome the error?

Tags: 12.10, error-handling, modem-manager

I am experiencing a error on Ubuntu 12.10. I have installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my laptop. On every re-start I see a popup describing the error.

Below is the snapshot of the pop window. I do not know how to solve and overcome the error.

The error title:

```
 modem-manager crashed with SIGSEGC in mm_plugin_base_supports_task_complete()
```

Executable path

```
    /user/sbin/modem-manager
```

Package

```
    modemmanager 0.6.00.really-0ubuntu1
```

Problem type

```
    crash
```

[image]

Comment: Does the error give you any problems? If not, just click 'Ignore future problems of this type' and click Continue. It's probably a bug with no fix if you can't find any on Google.

Comment: @Ads20000 the OS works fine otherwise. I can ignore the error. I was just not sure if this is caused due to some package missing or something that is not executed properly.

Comment: Well, normally dependencies are fine with default programs, so I assume that it is just something that wasn't executed properly.

Comment: @Ads20000 is there any fix if this is a bug. I had a option to report the same. I did.

Comment: It doesn't look like there is a fix sorry.

Answer (score 0):

### Workaround to prevent the message appearing:

Press "**Ignore Future Problem of This type**", and you will prevent the message showing every time you do it. There is no known fix for this error found by searching.

Comment: For those of you who edit my Answer: What is the problem being polite? It's not against the rules, neither any topics or information tells me to prevent being polite. Thanks